# I have a spoj puzzle. EOF error?

Tags: python

```
#!/usr/bin/env python


test_cases = int(raw_input())

for i in range(test_cases):
    x, y = map(int, raw_input().split())
for i in range(y):
    if_true = False
    for a in range(x):
        if if_true == False:
            print "*",
            if_true = True
            continue
        elif if_true == True:
            print ".",
            if_true = False
            continue
        print; print
```

This is the code for problem 3 of the basic set of problems. It is called Character Patterns (Act 1). I get an EOF error for the first raw_input and in ideone it, I see no input from the site...

`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 4, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Comment: I submitted your exact code at http://www.spoj.com/submit/CPTTRN1, and it ran successfully. (It produced the wrong output, but there was nothing like "an EOF error.") Can you describe exactly what error you saw where?

Comment: Well here is the stderr. `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog.py", line 4, in <module>
EOFError: EOF when reading a line`

Comment: What version of Python did you pick? I believe I picked 2.7.10. I'm just trying to guess what might be different. In any case, you should probably contact Sphere Online Judge support.

Comment: What does your output say? After you run it click on the ideone link and run it again on that site and you'll get your output... I'm of course running 2.7.10.

Comment: Did you enter anything in STDIN? Ideone.com doesn't provide any input unless you put it in there.

Comment: I used the input `1\n3 3` (with a real newline), and your code ran successfully.